# For-loop returning wrong results

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinity

I am getting wrong results resolving below task:

Generalized harmonic numbers. Write a program GeneralizedHarmonic.java that takes two integer command-line arguments n and r and uses a for loop to compute the nth generalized harmonic number of order r, which is defined by the following formula:
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBk9e.png)

```
public class GeneralizedHarmonic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int i;
        double sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
            sum += 1 / Math.pow(i, b);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

This is my code but I could not get the correct test output.The output result is always `Infinity`.
[test outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Qq6.png)

Comment: Why is this not the correct test output? The sample output from the formula states that H(3,2) is **approximately** equal to `1.361111`. Your program's output matches that.

Comment: Please copy the formula and your expected output as text directly into your question. I'm not gonna click your links.

Comment: But we don't know what is 'generalized harmonic number'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initliazed `int i = 0` in for-loop `for (i = 0; i <= a; i++)` and so the first element of your harmonic number isn't [image: \frac{1}{1^{b}}], but [image: ![\frac{1}{0^{b}}].

The code that works:

```java
public class GeneralizedHarmonic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            sum += 1 / Math.pow(i, b);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```